# Change wordpress theme based on URL

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I posted this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32523635/two-wordpress-sites-using-diiferent-themes-on-the-same-database) 2 days ago. What I wanted to do was to run 2 WordPress sites having different theme on the same database. I was advised that it couldn't be done and that I should replicate and use the same database for each.

However, I was wondering if there's any way I could change the theme based on the URL being accessed,

Something like this,

```
if (URL == "one.site.com") {
   LoadThemeOne();
}
else if (URL == "two.site.com") {
   LoadThemeTwo();
}
```

I appreciate any help, Thanks.

Comment: It would be easier to create two page templates on one wordpress installation and then to style it, and you can then just use different page template on different page.

Answer (score 1):

Sure it can be done. In fact, it's pretty easy if you use the [Jonradio Multiple Themes](https://wordpress.org/plugins/jonradio-multiple-themes/) plugin.